# Spectral theorem for compact normal operators

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory, linear-transformations

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $A$ a compact normal operator from $H$ to $H$. How to show that its eigenspaces produce the space? I can show it for self-adjoint operators and by setting $T(x)=A^*A(x)$, $T$ is self-adjoint so its eigenspaces produce H but how can I show it for $A$?

Comment: You could use the result mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition), namely: *every compact operator on a complex Banach space has a nest of closed invariant subspaces*.

Comment: It may also be useful that $\ker A = \ker A^*$

Comment: Thanks, I think I already got it. Don't know if my solution is correct though. I said that since all the eigenspaces of the non-zero eigenvalues of T are A-invariant and A*-invariant and that the eigenspaces have finite dimension then A is diagonizable in every eigenspace and since kerT=KerA then A is diagonizable in all H. Does that sound right?

Comment: Sounds right to me.  How did you show that the eigenvalues of $T$ are $A$ and $A^*$ invariant?

Comment: Because A is normal A* A=A A*, if x belongs to an eigenspace of T for the nonzero eigenvalue a then T(x) = A*(A(x)) = ax, so A(T(x)) = 
A(A* A(x)) = A* A(A(x)) = T(A(x)) = aA(x) and I did the same for A*

Comment: That looks good to me

Comment: Nice! Thanks! :D